# Updating a new asp.net core project to core 1.1 packages breaks the project

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

I just did a File new project in Visual Studio 2015 Community edition with update 3 and created a new Asp.NEt Core Mvc project.

I could build and start the project just fine.

Then I updated all nuget-packagges because many *.core.1.1 packages are available. After I did this, the project can no longer start when I do a simple f5. The browser opens and says the site cant be reached - probably because i fails to start. I tried setting a breakpoint in the main method in the Program.cs file, and that is not even hit. So it looks as if upgrading nuget packages breaks a standard ASP.Net Core project created from the official project template. The project is by deault set to use IIS Express.

Has anybody else experienced the same issue and found a solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you follow the guide here: [Announcing .NET Core 1.1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/11/16/announcing-net-core-1-1/)?

Beside just updating your packages other changes are required, like update of frameworks section in project.json file:

```
{
  ...
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.1": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "type": "platform",
          "version": "1.1.0"
        }
      },
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: No I somehow missed these instructions. Thanks !

Comment: and dont forget global.json to ensure version matches dotnet.exe version